# How can I decipher which graph belongs to which equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, graphing-functions

[image]

[image]

Aside from plotting points, how else can I tell which graph is which?

Comment: The only *apparent* differences between the graphs are of the kind "red is greater than blue for negative $x$" or similar. This makes plotting (or at least evaluating) one point a simple and efficient option - and ultimately the only one: If you show any other difference between the functions, you must still argue that this leads to the visible difference between the graohs, i.e., that $f(x)<g(x)$ for some negative $x$ or the like

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We know that $\ln (2) < \ln (7)$, if $x<0$, then

$$x\ln (2) > x \ln (7)$$

$$2^x>7^x$$

Similar for the second case, work with $\ln (4)$ and $\ln (3)$ to compare the graph.

Comment: ah thank you! i have a really dumb question but, why do we know that $\ln(2) < \ln(7)$? just by nature of the logarithm function or are you just computing it?

Comment: We know $\ln(x)$ is an increasing function.

Comment: This answer is only "natural" if you know of $\ln$ and the $\exp$ (exponential function with base $e$). Going from $x\ln(2)>x\ln(7)$ to $2^x>7^x$ requires that you take $\exp$ and both sides and know that $\exp$ is an increasing function. It is possible that the reader has learned about $2^x$ and $7^x$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ without using $\exp$ as the definition. Maybe it would be more natural to use "exponentiation rules" on the quotient between $2^x$ and $7^x$ and appeal to whatever weak definition being used to find out if the quotient is greater than or less than one?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the 1st graph.

For x<0, 2<sup>x</sup> > 7<sup>x</sup>

So now you need to determine which curve is having higher values for the same values of x

The curve taking higher values for same values of x will always be above the curve taking lower values for same values of x.

So, the red curve is 2<sup>x</sup> and the blue curve is 7<sup>x</sup>

Consider the 2nd graph

i) x > 0

3<sup>-x</sup> > 4<sup>-x</sup>

So, 3 <sup>-x</sup> will be higher in the region x<0

ii) x < 0

4<sup>-x</sup> > 3<sup>-x</sup>

So, 4<sup>-x</sup> will be higher in the region x<0

By observing the graph it can be concluded that the red curve is 4<sup>-x</sup> and the blue curve is 3<sup>-x</sup>